# client.on not getting data on single connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, socket.io

I am using [`net`](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/net/#net_event_connect) module to connect client with my server. And here is my code.

```
        const Net = require('net');

        client = Net.connect(parseInt(port), host, function() {
          console.log('server connected')
        })
        console.log("ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
        client.on('data', function(chunk) {
          let data = chunk.toString()
          console.log(data)
        });
        client.on('error', function(error) {
          console.error('error', error);
        });
```

The issue is when I connect it with single client it doesn't give me data inside `client.on('data'` but when I connect it will two or more clients it gets connected and I am getting my data. Someone pls help.

If there any other module I can use ?

Comment: Are you sure chunk.toString is a function? If it isn't, it could stop the function and never make it to the console.log.

Comment: @Ollie yes chunk.toString is a function and I am getting the data but when two clients get connected when connect with first one it does not give me the data.

Comment: What type is the server, TCP? if so, then the `net` module is easiest used to send text or JSON objects back to your Node client. If so I'll give an example of my current project.

Comment: It is a TCP server. But please check the issue above @WLGfx

Comment: My answer posted may not be exactly what you're looking for, but may be of help. The flush of the TCP servers output was essential for mine to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have three Java TCP servers each running on their own thread, this particular one handles localhost connections from the NodeJS server which is mainly TEXT or JSON objects. It will read a command and respond.

The NodeJS server then sends that data back to the client browser using `socket.io`.

```
/*
* Handle the nodejs interaction on localhost port 2000
*/
public class DeviceServer3 extends Thread {

    private static DeviceServer dev_server = null;
    private boolean quit = false;
    private final int port = 2000;

    public DeviceServer3(DeviceServer server) {
        dev_server = server; // store original server
    }

    public void quitSignal() { // safely shutdown thread
        System.out.println("WLMedia Node Java Server exiting...");
        quit = true;

        while (dev_server.thread_count.get() != 0) {
            try { Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { // main thread
        ServerSocket listen_socket = null;

        while (!quit) {
            try {
                listen_socket = new ServerSocket(port);
                //listen_socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                listen_socket.setReuseAddress(true);

                while (!quit) {
                    Socket connection = listen_socket.accept();
                    checkSocket(connection);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Node Server catch: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (listen_socket != null) {
                        listen_socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("server finally: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkSocket(Socket socket) {
        // Only allow 'localhost' connections
        if (socket.getInetAddress().isLoopbackAddress()) {
            handleSocket(socket); // TODO change to a thread
        } else {
            System.out.println("WARNING: Outside connection attempt from: "
                    + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
        }

        try {
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Port 2000 socket disconnected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private BufferedReader getBufferedReader(Socket socket)
            throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        return new BufferedReader(is);
    }

    private BufferedWriter getBufferedWriter(Socket socket)
            throws IOException {
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        return new BufferedWriter(os);
    }

    // Safely here to handle the socket connection
    private void handleSocket(Socket socket) {
        System.out.println("Port 2000 socket connected");

        try {
            BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(socket);
            BufferedWriter bw = getBufferedWriter(socket);

            String command = br.readLine();

            switch (command) {
                
                /* Media Manager */
                
                case "media_areas":
                    System.out.println("NodeJS media_areas");
                    get_media_areas(br, bw);
                    break;

                case "media_categories":
                    System.out.println("NodeJS media_categories");
                    get_media_categories(br, bw);
                    break;
                
                /* Device manager */
                    
                case "devices_get":
                    System.out.println("NodeJS get_devices");
                    get_devices(br, bw);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("NodeJS command not recognised: " + command);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
    * Handle commands
    */
    // Command: media_areas
    private void get_media_areas(BufferedReader br, BufferedWriter bw)
            throws IOException {
        JSONArray area_list = new JSONArray(); // create JSON array

        System.out.println("Getting Area list");

        synchronized (dev_server.library.media_lock) {
            for (Area area : dev_server.library.media) {
                area_list.put(area.name);
                System.out.println("Area: " + area.name);
            }
        }

        bw.write(area_list.toString()); // send JSON array back to NodeJS server
        bw.flush(); // ensure a flush before the socket is closed
    }
    
    // ...
```

The issue I had was the data not being sent to the Node server, which using the `flush()` fixed that issue before the socket was closed.

This is a snipped from the Node server which connects to the Java TCP server and then sends the JSON data back to the clients browser.

```
const global = require("../global/global.js");
const login = require("../login/login");
const node_port = 2000;
const host = "localhost";

function m_get_media_areas(socket) {
    // check user logged in (return to login page)
    if (!login.check_logged_in(socket)) { return; }
    
    client = new global.net.Socket(); // connect to Java TCP server
    client.connect({port: node_port, host: host}, () =>
        { client.write("media_areas\n"); });
    
    // send the JSON string to clients browser over socket.io
    client.on("data", (data) => { socket.emit("media_areas", data); });
    
    client.on("end", () => {});
    client.on("error", () => { console.log("ERROR: getting areas"); });
}

module.exports = {
get_media_areas : m_get_media_areas,
// ...
}
```

On the clients browser side I just use `socket.io` to emit the command and then just listent for the event so that I can use the data.

```
// get area list
socket.emit("media_areas");

// media variables

media_area = "";
media_category = "";
media_videos = {}; // a JSON array of JSON objects

socket.on("media_areas", (res) => {
    json = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(res));
    
    $("#list_media_area").empty();
    $("#list_media_category").empty();
    $("#list_media_videos").empty();
    
    json.forEach(area => {
        if (area !== null && area !== "")
            $("#list_media_area").append("<li>" + area);
    });
    
    media_area = "";
    
    $("#list_media_area li").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("li_selected").siblings().removeClass("li_selected");
        media_area = $(this).text();
        console.log("Media Area Selected: " + media_area);
        $("#accordion_video_category").click();
        socket.emit("media_categories", {"area": media_area});
    });
});
```

That's how I've managed to get around it and it works for me great.

The Java JSON library I used is:
https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.json%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json%22

Comment: My project is split into many files, so global vars are referenced from there. Such as express, net, socket.io, and many others. It just cleans up my code. They are all set in main.js on startup.

Comment: NB: When sending data to the TCP server from Node, make sure you append `\n` to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information on your server implementation it is difficult to answer this question directly. Here is a general example that should be helpful for you.

server.js

```
const net = require('net');

net.createServer(function(socket) {

  // listen for data from the client
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data from client: ', String(data));
  });

  // write data to the client
  socket.write('hello from the server\n');

}).listen('3000', function() {
  console.log('server listening on 3000');
});
```

client.js

```
const net = require('net');

const socket = net.connect(3000, 'localhost')

// listen for data from the server
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('data from server: ', String(data));
});

// write data to the server
socket.write('hello from the client\n');
```

First run `node server.js` then from a separate tab run `node client.js`. You should see the communication between the server and client. Another tool that may be helpful for you is `telnet`, which provides a simple tcp interface. You can test your server by using `telnet localhost 3000`